# Upload and preview GLTF File (3D)

Tags: angular, three.js

Is there a way to preview a .gltf (3D) file from an input type file?
I tried to upload the 3D file but nothing appears to me.
Does anyone know if it is possible to solve my problem?
I've tested everything but I still haven't got any results. glTF needs to be "converted" before it can be displayed.

Thank you

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-three-flexbox-d1d5ty?file=src%2Fapp%2Fthree-canvas%2Fthree-canvas.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <input id="file-input" type="file"
(change)="mychange($event)" />
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```

**.TS**

```
 mychange(e){
   let file = e.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function ( gltfText ) {
  const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  {
    const planeSize = 40;

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/checker.png');
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    const repeats = planeSize / 2;
    texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);

    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  {
    const skyColor = 0xB1E1FF;  // light blue
    const groundColor = 0xB97A20;  // brownish orange
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(skyColor, groundColor, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(5, 10, 2);
    scene.add(light);
    scene.add(light.target);
  }

  function frameArea(sizeToFitOnScreen, boxSize, boxCenter, camera) {
    const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = sizeToFitOnScreen * 0.5;
    const halfFovY = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov * .5);
    const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);
    const direction = (new THREE.Vector3())
        .subVectors(camera.position, boxCenter)
        .multiply(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1))
        .normalize();

    camera.position.copy(direction.multiplyScalar(distance).add(boxCenter));
    camera.near = boxSize / 100;
    camera.far = boxSize * 100;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    camera.lookAt(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, boxCenter.z);
  }

  {
    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
   gltfLoader.parse( gltfText.target.result, '', function( gltf ){
      const root = gltf.scene;
      scene.add(root);
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);
      const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
      const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
      frameArea(boxSize * 0.5, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);
      controls.maxDistance = boxSize * 10;
      controls.target.copy(boxCenter);
      controls.update();
    });
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);

    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) does support this use case. The idea is to use the `FileReader` API. For loading a `glb` file, the code would look like so:

```js
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    const contents = event.target.result;

    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.parse( contents, '', function ( gltf ) {

        const scene = gltf.scene;
        console.log( scene );

    } );

}, false );
reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
```

The `file` variable is an instance of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). The related code in the `three.js` editor is located in [Loader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/editor/js/Loader.js).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I select a .gltf file I get the following error:'InvalidStateError: The source image could not be decoded.'

Comment: Your code works for me without issues. Keep in mind that you need a different code for loading glTF assets with the `.gltf` extension. The above code only works for `.glb`.

Comment: I tried to convert my gltf to glb. When inserting my new glb nothing came up. I tried with other glb files that I downloaded on the internet and it didn't work either :(

Comment: In your stackblitz live example, you still have to add `gltf.scene` to your `scene`. I've added `console.log( scene );` just for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for everything. At this point I get the following error: Object too large to inspect. Open your browser console to view. . The 3D image still doesn't appear to me :(